# Cannot set property 'name' of undefined JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand JavaScript prototype and when I attempted coding this I get an error:

```
function Person(firstname, last name) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
}

var A = new Person('John', 'Doe');

A.prototype.name = 'Toby';
```

I get an error stating cannot set property 'name' of undefined. Can't i assign a property on it's prototype of Object A. This is just a simple exercise to get an understanding of prototypes

Comment: `first name`, `last name`, variable name cannot contain space

Comment: @Tushar thanks corrected it. Typo error. Still having the error though cannot set the property name

Comment: `A.prototype....` => `Person.prototype....`

Comment: After you fix your syntax errors (spaces inside variable names), you should set the prototype property of the "class" (`Person`), not of the object you instantiate (`A`).

Comment: @torazaburo why not the object instantiated.

Comment: Because that's not how you do it.

Comment: @torazaburo so basically when the Object A was created it inherits the base Object prototype right.

Answer (score 3):

Objects don't have a prototype property (unless you create one). You usually only assign to the `prototype` property of constructors:

```
function Person(firstname, lastname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
}

Person.prototype.name = 'Toby';

var A = new Person('John', 'Doe');

// A.name === 'Toby';
```

Comment: Now everyone's named Toby.